# Replacing regex with optional pattern

Tags: python, regex

I want to convert time separator from the French way to a more standard way:

- "17h30" becomes "17:30"
- "9h" becomes "9:00"

Using regexp I can transform `17h30` to `17:30` but I did not find an elegant way of transforming `9h` into `9:00`

Here's what I did so far:

```py
import re
texts = ["17h30", "9h"]
hour_regex = r"(\d?\d)h(\d\d)?"
[re.sub(hour_regex, r"\1:\2", txt) for txt in texts]
>>> ['17:30', '9:']
```

What I want to do is "if \2 did not match anything, write 00".

PS: Of course I could use a more detailed regex like "([12]?\d)h[0123456]\d" to be more precise when matching hours, but this is not the point here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Effectively*** with `re.compile` function and `or` condition:

```
import re

texts = ["17h30", "9h"]
hour_regex = re.compile(r"(\d{1,2})h(\d\d)?")
res = [hour_regex.sub(lambda m: f'{m.group(1)}:{m.group(2) or "00"}', txt) 
       for txt in texts]
print(res)   # ['17:30', '9:00']
```

Comment: Ok, so it works, but it doesn't *only* use regex. For info, I'm using Python 3.5 which doesn't have f-strings, so I'm using `format`: `hour_regex.sub(lambda m: "{0}:{1}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2) or "00"), txt)`. I'm accepting your answer, but if someone provides an answer which only uses regex, this would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a slight (crooked) way:

```
import re

texts = ["17h30", "9h"]
hour_regex = r"(\d?\d)h(\d\d)?"

print([re.sub(r':$', ':00', re.sub(hour_regex, r"\1:\2", txt)) for txt in texts])
# ['17:30', '9:00']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but I prefer Roman's way of doing.